# How can I rename all keys in a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to rename the dict keys in Python.

There are two keys, 'Curry_Vegetables_Set1 (59).JPG131850' and 'Curry_Vegetables_Set1 (62).JPG104359', which I want to rename with replace1 value. How can I rename them?

Below is the dict sample:

```
file = {'Curry_Vegetables_Set1 (59).JPG131850': {'filename': '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_59.jpg',
  'size': 131850,
  'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
     'all_points_x': [510, 563,622,],
     'all_points_y': [459,  523, 505,]},
    'region_attributes': {'food': 'curry_vegetable'}}],
  'file_attributes': {}},
 'Curry_Vegetables_Set1 (62).JPG104359': {'filename': '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_62.jpg',
  'size': 104359,
  'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
     'all_points_x': [471,490,528,],
     'all_points_y': [496,476,493]},
    'region_attributes': {'food': 'curry_vegetable'}}],
  'file_attributes': {}},}
```

I tried the code below,

```
for key,value in file.items():
    name = key.split('.')
    num = name[0].split('(')
    image_num = num[1][:-1]
    replace1 = '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_'+image_num+'.'+name[1]

    # replace old keys with replace1
    file[replace1] = file[key]
```

but it gives error as:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: The answers below solve the problem well. The overall thing to remember is that you should not insert or remove elements from a container while iterating over it. Here you got an exception, but with a list you might have just gotten unpredictable results. Instead, you can copy the list of keys into a list (using `list(file.items())`, see @Bhagyesh's solution) and iterate over that, or create a whole new data structure altogether (see other two solutions), then you avoid these conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really changing the old keys; you're adding new ones to the same dictionary. You should create a new empty dictionary and add the new key/value pairs to that in the loop.

```
file2 = {}
for key, value in file.items():
    name = key.split('.')
    num = name[0].split('(')
    image_num = num[1][:-1]
    replace1 = '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_' + image_num + '.' + name[1]

    # replace old keys with replace1
    file2[replace1] = file[key]
    
print(file2)
```

Comment: thanks, changed accordingly
new_file = {}
for key,value in file.items():
    name = key.split('.')
    num = name[0].split('(')  
    image_num = num[1][:-1]   
    replace1 = '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_'+image_num+'.'+name[1] 
    new_file[replace1] = file[key]

Answer (score 2):

The reason to get `RunTimeError` is you are updating the dict which is already loaded using `file.items()`. Casting the dictionary items to `list` creates a list of its items, so you can iterate over it and avoid the `RunTimeError`.

```
file = {'Curry_Vegetables_Set1 (59).JPG131850': {'filename': '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_59.jpg',
    'size': 131850,
    'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [510, 563,622,], 'all_points_y': [459,  523, 505,]},
    'region_attributes': {'food': 'curry_vegetable'}}],
    'file_attributes': {}
},
    'Curry_Vegetables_Set1 (62).JPG104359': {'filename': '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_62.jpg',
    'size': 104359,
    'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [471,490,528,], 'all_points_y': [496,476,493]},
    'region_attributes': {'food': 'curry_vegetable'}}],
  'file_attributes': {}},
}
for key,value in list(file.items()):
    name = key.split('.')
    num = name[0].split('(')  
    image_num = num[1][:-1]   
    replace1 = '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_'+image_num+'.'+name[1] 
    file[replace1] = file[key]
    del file[key]
print (file)
```

Output:

```
{'1.5_Curry_Vegetables_59.JPG131850': {'filename': '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_59.jpg', 'size': 131850, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [510, 563, 622], 'all_points_y': [459, 523, 505]}, 'region_attributes': {'food': 'curry_vegetable'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_62.JPG104359': {'filename': '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_62.jpg', 'size': 104359, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'all_points_x': [471, 490, 528], 'all_points_y': [496, 476, 493]}, 'region_attributes': {'food': 'curry_vegetable'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}}
```

Comment: Earlier I had just provided a pseudocode to do it, have updated the entire code which solves the `RunTimeError` and also updates the key name

Comment: This works, thanks for updating your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Inplace:

```py
oldKeys = list(dictionary.keys())
for oldKey in oldKeys:
    name = oldKey .split('.')
    num = name[0].split('(')
    image_num = num[1][:-1]
    newKey = '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_' + image_num + '.' + name[1]
    dictionary[newKey] = dictionary.pop(oldKey)
```

Or via creating a new dict:

```py
def newKeyFromOld(oldKey):
    name = oldKey .split('.')
    num = name[0].split('(')
    image_num = num[1][:-1]
    newKey = '1.5_Curry_Vegetables_' + image_num + '.' + name[1]
    return newKey
{newKeyFromOld(oldKey): value for oldKey, value in dictionary.items()}
```

Comment: The first solution above still produces the `RuntimeError` reported by OP.

Comment: Thanks for the comment joanis, I've changed it

Comment: Please test your solutions before posting them. I still get the same exception, because `dictionary.keys()` does not copy the list of keys, it returns an iterator into the keys, and so this code is still trying to modify `dictionary` during iteration. In Python 2, your code would work because `keys()` returned a list, but the question was specifically tagged Python 3, where `keys()` returns an iterator.